# Как узнать кодировку переменной?

Tags: php

Как узнать кодировку переменной?

Comment: Знаете как найти ответ? Копируем название вопроса и вставляем строку поиска, жмем Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mb_detect_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)